# What language/library can I use to do 2D text animations like after effects?

Tags: animation, text, 2d, moviepy

I want to code custom text animations similar to what you would see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jI2WSh7w2IY) but instead of using a motion graphics program like After Effects, I want to code it by hand. In that way I can crate an animation sequence and use the text as variables. The final output will be video.

So far I have encountered [moviepy's text animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj5qrHl5ZS0) but there are some limitations, I'm wondering what are the other options out there. My Googling only brought up pygame but it wasn't clear on the capabilities with respect to text animations. I also found [Greensock Javascript animation](https://greensock.com/SplitText), but there was no easy way to programatically create high frame rate videos from a web browser.

Any language is fine.